# HSQLDB 2.3.3: How to create type java list?

Tags: hsqldb

Can we create **custom type** which is of type `java.util.List`?

```
CREATE TYPE list
EXTERNAL NAME 'java.util.List'
LANGUAGE JAVA;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I am having some junit mock implementation which returns list.  See sample procedure for example `CREATE TYPE list
EXTERNAL NAME 'java.util.List'
LANGUAGE JAVA;

CREATE PROCEDURE MyStorProc (
    test_column1 VARCHAR(30),
    test_column2 VARCHAR(30),
    OUT Out_column_Name list)
    PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
    LANGUAGE JAVA
    READS SQL DATA
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
    EXTERNAL NAME 'com.mypackage.name.selectRows'
;`

Answer (score 0):

Types can be created based on an existing supported type, so this cannot be used for your purpose.

The SQL equivalent of a list is an ARRAY. You should use an array such as INTEGER ARRAY, or VARCHAR(100) ARRAY. The Java form of the array to use in the Java static method is Object[].